# antlr v3 lexer predicts wrong

Tags: antlr3

consider the following (combined) grammar

```
grammar CastModifier;
tokens{
 E='=';
 C='=()';
 Lp='(';
 Rp=')';
 I = 'int';
 S=';';
}

compilationUnit
    : assign+ EOF
    ;

assign
    :   '=' Int ';'
    |   '=' '(' 'int' ')' Int ';'
    |   '=()' Int ';'
    ;

Int
    :   ('1'..'9') ('0'..'9')*
        |    '0'
        ;

Whitespace  
    :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

Unfortunately the lexer does not always predict the next token correctly. For instance for the following code

```
=(int) 1;
```

The Lexer predicts it must be the '=()' token. It detects the correct token for the following code

= (int) 1;

I figured this problem should be solvable by ANTLR if I provide the following option for the rule "assign":

```
options{k=3;}
```

But apparently it does not help and neither if I define this option for the whole grammar. How can I resolve this problem? My workaround at the moment is to built the '=()' token out of '='('')' but that allows the user to write

= ()

Which, well, is kind of ok but I am just wondering why ANTLR is not able to predict it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `options{k=3;}` causes the parser to look ahead at most 3 tokens, not the lexer. ANTLR3's lexer is not that *smart*: once it matches a character, it won't give up on that match. So, in your case, from the input `=(int) 1;`, `=(` is matched but then there is an `i` in the char stream and no token that matches this.

> My workaround at the moment is to built the '=()' token out of '='('')'

I'd call that a proper solution: `'='` `'('` and `')'` *are* separate tokens and should be handled as such (to be glued together in the parser, not the lexer).

Comment: I wonder, you said "ANTLR3's lexer is not that smart", do you imply that ANTLR4's Lexer is smarter? And may I ask you for your opinion. Do you think it is bad that one can write "=()" and "= ()" ? I just realised that you can write "int?" and "int ?" in C# - so I guess it is ok - or do you have a solution to forbid "= ()" (I am ignoring white spaces)?